# React-router - Issue accessing route through url

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom

Basically I need my user to reset their password, accessing a page directly through a url (from the mail they receive).
The routes work fine when using history.push, or when used directly (in the url) - running on localhost. When site is running on server however, typing the path gives a 404.

I'm assuming its due to the last part needing to be run on the server, but I don't know how to do that.

Was looking into HashRouter, but I don't want all my urls to have '#' in them.

Any ideas? Cheers

```js
    <BrowserRouter>
      <div>
        <Switch>
          <Route path="/" component={SignIn} exact />
          <Route path="/signup" component={SignUp} exact />
          <Route path="/forgotpassword" component={ForgotPassword} exact />
          <Route path="/resetpassword" component={ResetPassword} exact />
          <ProtectedRoute exact path="/app" component={Home} /> */
          <Route path="*" component={() => "404 NOT FOUND"} />
        </Switch>
      </div>
    </BrowserRouter>
```

Comment: you need to implement server-side routing as well. I would suggest using a framework like nextjs or gatsby. Dont write your own router, its a waste of dev time.

Comment: You need SSR for your react application, you should try to rewrite your whole app using Next.js, it will help a lot https://nextjs.org/. Trying to make your react-app to have SSR it will just create more headaches, I tried it too and I had a lot of problems with bundling and webpack.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, both of you :). I will have a look at the frameworks suggested. Kind of surprised it should be this complicated. - Cheers

Answer (score 0):

Considering this is the only page I have to access from the outside, I went the route of checking the location.search for extra params when hitting '/'.

It defaults to showing signin, but will return resetpassword component e.g. if https://example.net?resetpassword.

Its not pretty, but it works - and this is only for an exam, not client :D

Route looks like this.

```js
          <Route path="/" component={(props) =>
          {
            if (props.location.search.includes('?resetpassword'))
              return <ResetPassword {...props} />
            else
              return <SignIn {...props} />
          }} exact />
```